# Unable to load service index for source when build the docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nuget, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package-restore

I've a simple *gRpc* application, classic *HelloWorld* which comes along with an operation *SayHello*.
I added in this project a reference to a nuget package stored in our corporate feed (let's call the source hereafter *https://my_corporate_feed/nuget/v3/index.json*).

Then I added the Docker support to my project using the functionality provided by VisualStudio 2022 and I get this Dockerfile generated for me

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["nuget.config", "."]
COPY ["Greteer/Greteer.csproj", "Greteer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Greteer/Greteer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Greteer"
RUN dotnet build "Greteer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Greteer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Greteer.dll"]
```

Nothing complicated so far. But, when I try to build and publish this docker file, I got an error during the RestoreTask.
The error reports: ***error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://my_corporate_feed/nuget/v3/index.json***
I've followed already some suggestions from SO users (ex. set dns for the docker daemon to [8.8.8.8]) but nothing works. I don't think that is a problem of connectivity because the normal packages (gRpc and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) are restored correctly. I think the problem is just my feed source. Has anyone of use face similar issue? Thanks

Comment: Hi, where do you "build and publish this docker file"? By the way, there should have a second error output under this error, that error will tell you what truely happened. How you connect to this feed directly, does it needs some credentials, if so, you may need to pass the credentials into docker file. :)

Comment: Yes, I fixed this issue by generating a Personal Access Toekn (with just the Packaging read scope) and use it in my credentials :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you confirmed, this issue needs you  to pass credentials like PAT token into the dockerfile, otherwise it will be impossible to access the feed.

By the way, this type of issue always have secondary error output, you can use fiddler to capture the network trace. In this way, you will get the actual cause of the issue.